# Error: Projection: The CRS of a map projection could not be parsed. (Error code: 3)

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, google-earth-engine, export

I transferred the image I exported from Google Earth Engine to QGIS. I am getting projection error in my work. Anyone have an idea about this?

When I want to export in WGS 84 EPSG:7030 I get the error 'Error: Projection: The CRS of a map projection could not be parsed. (Error code: 3)'

```
Export.image.toDrive({ 
  image: afterFiltered2,
  description: 'afterFiltered2_subat2015',
  fileNamePrefix: 'afterFiltered2_subat2015',
  folder: 'GEE_after_filtered_2015_subat',
  scale: 30, 
  region: studyarea,
  crs:'EPSG:7030'
  });
```

Comment: add my code below

Comment: Change `EPGS` to `EPSG`.

Comment: thank you i fixed it but i keep getting the same error

Comment: @ezgitekin edit your question and change it in the code aswell

Comment: EPSG:7030 isn't an EPSG code for a CRS.  it may refer to an ellipsoid, or to a transformation ~ see the EPSG registry ~ https://epsg.org/search/by-name/?query=7030&displayTabs=more

Answer (score 4):

That error (among possibly other things) indicates that the CRS code you provided is not supported by Earth Engine.

If a CRS code you are interested in using is not recognized by Earth Engine via CRS code, you can provide the projection as WKT using the [`ee.Projection`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-projection) constructor. Both cases are demonstrated in the code sample below for the World Robinson CRS code 'ESRI:54030'.

Also, I took a quick look to see if I could find the WKT for code 'EPSG:7030' and could not. I then looked for it in the supported QGIS (v3.10.0) projections and it didn't come up. Is there a different projection you can use?

```js
// World Robinson CRS code from ESRI is not supported by Earth Engine.
var projFromCode = ee.Projection('ESRI:54030');
print('CRS code not supported', projFromCode);

// You can define the CRS using WKT string though (https://epsg.io/54030).
var projFromWKT = ee.Projection(
  'PROJCS["World_Robinson",' +
      'GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",' +
          'DATUM["WGS_1984",' +
              'SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137,298.257223563]],' +
          'PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],' +
          'UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],' +
      'PROJECTION["Robinson"],' +
      'UNIT["Meter",1]]'
);
print('Use WKT string for non-code supported projections', projFromWKT);
```