Pixel values became smaller after aggregation on GEE
I am aggregating burned area pixel (500m) on GEE into larger pixel. The idea is to sum up the values of the burned area and aggregating into bigger pixel. As the image below, it is expected to see the small burned area being summed to represent the bigger pixel. So after aggregating the pixel from 500m to 20km resolution, the value of the bigger pixel will be 4km2.

Therefore, when turning into bigger pixel, the value will be bigger since it includes more burned area pixels. However, after trying different resolution, I found out the the values became smaller instead. As the image shown below:

I used Google Earth Engine to aggregate the pixel and calculate it. This is the link to the script (https://code.earthengine.google.com/f9f5049c6ab71beaa9fb18f4881c104c). The main function I used is reduceResolution. The main part of the code is as follow:
// Function to calculate the sum of burned area within a larger pixel
var calculateBASum = function(image) {
  // Apply the QA mask
  image = good(image);
  
  // Create a binary mask where BurnDate is greater than 0 (indicating burned area)
  var burned = image.select('BurnDate').gt(0);

  // Calculate the area of each 500m pixel (in square meters)
  var pixelArea = ee.Image.pixelArea().multiply(burned);

  // Resample to 10000m by summing the area of burned pixels within each 10000m pixel
  var resampled = pixelArea.reduceResolution({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(), // Use sum to aggregate burned areas
    maxPixels: 1826
  }).reproject({
    crs: customProj,
    scale: 10000
  });

  return resampled;
};
// Filter MODIS collection for a specific month
var start = ee.Date('2016-09-01');
var end = start.advance(1, 'month');
var coll = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/061/MCD64A1')
    .filterBounds(ROI)
    .filterDate(start, end)  // Add date filtering here
    .map(calculateBASum);

// Sum the burned area images for the month
var monthlySum = coll.sum().set({
  'system:time_start': start.millis(),
  'month': start.format('YYYY_MM')
});

// Reproject the monthlySum to custom projection before exporting
var reprojectedMonthlySum = monthlySum.reproject({
  crs: customProj,
  scale: 10000
}); 

I wonder if I understood the function wrongly so the operation is averaging the value instead of summing them up.

The problem can be partially solved by forcing projection of ee.Image.pixelArea() raster, but that would not solve that your custom projection is not the same as MODIS and so pixels are not aligned. Also see here

Don't use reproject unless absolutely necessary

Here is one way to write the function to do what you are trying to do
// MODIS Projection
var proj = coll.first().projection()
// MODIS original scale
var Mscale = proj.nominalScale()  // 463.31271652791656
// MODIS pixelArea
var PixelArea = Mscale.multiply(Mscale)  // 463.31271652791656^2 = 214658.67329647756
// Your desired aggreagtion
var NewScale = Mscale.multiply(20) // the aggregation scale  MODIS scale * 20 

// Function to calculate the sum of burned area within a larger pixel
var calculateBASum = function(image) {
  // Apply the QA mask
    image = good(image);
  // Create a binary mask where BurnDate is greater than 0 (indicating burned area)
    var mask = image.select('BurnDate').gt(0);

  // Resample by counting burned pixels in the new scale and muliplying with with pixel areas
    var resampled = mask.reduceResolution({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.count(), // Use count to count pixel with burned areas
    maxPixels: 1826
    }).reproject({
    crs: proj,
    scale: NewScale
      }).multiply(PixelArea) // multiply the number of pixel with hard coded pixel area 
     return resampled;
    };

In this function, count is used with `reduceResolution' to count the pixel inside map function and multiply the outcome with a hard coded pixel area instead. To guarantee pixel alignment and avoid unnecessary reprojection, you can finish the analysis in MODIS projection and, at the end, export to your preferred projection. Here is a revised code

thank you for the solution. The reason that I reproject first is that the error happens when I only reproject it at the ''export'' step. I used the code you provided above but when I downloaded the data, the error says: Error: Projection: The CRS of a map projection could not be parsed. (Error code: 3). Does it mean it is not possible to output the data with my customized projection.

I suppose you should be able to export normally, but you can try to reproject before export. The point is to reporoject after at the end after analysis, notice the pixel alignments https://code.earthengine.google.com/bf503dc713e89e75fb88499718ac2450

it is still showing the same error '' Error: Projection: The CRS of a map projection could not be parsed. (Error code: 3)'' even if I reprojected at the end (the code above).

It looks like this issue occurs regardless of the aggregation code as earth engine doesn't recognize the custom projection https://code.earthengine.google.com/a4760339accdb44f8ed06c7e2ca277c2
Have you exported with this custom projection before or can you work with other one for your area. See the question here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/438338/error-projection-the-crs-of-a-map-projection-could-not-be-parsed-error-code

Yes, that is probably because I customized this projection based on my study area. However, my initial code (https://code.earthengine.google.com/f9f5049c6ab71beaa9fb18f4881c104c) works when exporting based on my custom projection. So I don't understand why it is not working at this case...

Your code does not specify projection in the export. I edited the revised code in the answer to work in the same way

Thank you! Yes I think that it probably the solution. It is ok to include reprojection in the code but not during the export function. This code finally works with a customized projection!
https://code.earthengine.google.com/6a78de4a0bd64200cb6716eccea4c0fd
